# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in Apache Tomcat 9.0

Tags: fetch-api, tomcat9

The below image contains the description of preflight request error I am facing while accessing app hosted on my Tomcat 9.0.

[image]

I have tried almost everything on Tomcat from applying CORS filter to using content-type in my headers of fetch API which can be seen below:

CORS filter applied as directed over here :

[image]

```
  const res = fetch("url",
  {
    headers : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

  }).then(function(res){
    res.text().then(function (data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    })
  });
```

Nothing seems to be working on any given webapp published by me it's just throwing the same error. Requesting whoever sees this please help me out I am stuck on this for quite a long time!!!